# Is there a bug with Bootstrap 5.0 dropdown-menu-end alignment?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am unable to get dropdown-menu-end from Bootstrap 5.0 to work on in Angular even though I replicated the exact same code from https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_dropdowns.php.

The html appearance using my code from vsc is as follows: [site appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urtnl.png)

Hence, I would like to check whether is there a known bug with dropdown-menu-end? Or is there something wrong with my code? Thanks all.

P.S. I did install Bootstrap and imported               "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" into angular.json under styles.

```
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>Add the .dropdown-menu-end class to .dropdown-menu to right-align the dropdown menu.</p>

  <div class="dropdown dropdown-menu-end">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
      Wide dropdown button to demonstrate this example
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu show">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue @XIII did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Apply Class Name

`<div class="dropdown dropdown-menu-end">` to `<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end show">`

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
      Wide dropdown button to demonstrate this example
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end show"> /***Add Here***/
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm... I tried that but my dropdown still appears on the left.